# VBA Copy Cells For i IF

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on learning VBA but still very rough

I am trying to create a macro that will compile a report for the tasks that are assigned to an employee in another workbook. I am not using all of the rows.

The issue is that the macro is returning all of the tasks not just the ones that are assigned to the designated employee.

I think that my problem in occurring because I am using both For and If statements.

Thank you for your help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Import_Open_Jobs()
Dim DestinWB As Workbook: Set DestinWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook: Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\...\Open Tasks    Report.xlsx")
Dim ci As Integer
DestinWB.Activate
    Sheets("Open Tasks").Range("A3").Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            Intersect(Range("A:P"), ActiveCell.EntireRow).Clear
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

SourceWB.Activate
SourceWB.Sheets("Task_List").Range("A2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

'F1 contains the name of the employee that the report is created for.
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Range("F1") Then 


        For ci = 3 To 10000
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit For
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 2).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 3).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 4).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 5).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 15)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 6).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 22)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 7).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 23)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 8).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 24)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""",""NA"",IF(RC[-1]="""",""NA"",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-2],RC[-1])))"
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]="""",""NA"",IF(RC[-2]="""",""NA"",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-3],R1C4,)))"
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 11).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 27)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 12).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 16)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 13).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 21)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 14).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 18)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 15).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 19)
            DestinWB.Sheets("Open Tasks").Cells(ci, 16).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 20)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next ci
    Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

Loop
SourceWB.Close
DestinWB.Activate
Range("D1").Value = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
Columns("F:H").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you testing for the employee name?

Comment: It appears you are going through and doing things with a number of cells in the same row.  Can you simply copy and paste the entire row?  Can you post a sample of your spreadsheet?

Comment: You have improper nesting of For Loop and If Statement. i.e Next ci should be after ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select End If.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the IF inside the For loop, not outside.

If I understand correctly, you want to go through all the cells and if the condition matches, bring it over.

What you're currently doing if the value at first cell matches, bring in the next 10000